# Xubuntu: How to reset a menu accelerator?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gtk

I'm running Xubuntu 15.10 and I recently discovered GTK menu accelerators (http://docs.xfce.org/faq) and find them incredibly useful. I can easily set them and I know that hitting Backspace will clear one. However, how can I reset it back to the original shortcut? I know that I could manually reset it to whatever it was but I was wondering if there was an easier way just to reset it back to the default shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way: delete the menu accelerators' configuration files, then restart the applications to take effect. No need to logout or reboot the system at all.

### Where are the config files

The configuration files are found as `accels.scm` per application basis, per user. To list down all existing files for current user, run the following command and see its output.

```
$ locate accels
/home/USERNAME/.config/Mousepad/accels.scm
/home/USERNAME/.config/Thunar/accels.scm
/home/USERNAME/.config/ristretto/accels.scm
```

`USERNAME` refers to the name of current user.

There are only three matching results by default (in Xubuntu 14.04), which are menu acceleration configuration files for Mousepad text editor, Thunar file manager, and ristretto image viewer.

### Missing config files

As hinted above, not all applications have the configuration files by default.

For example, Xfce Terminal will not create `accels.scm` file for current user, unless the menu accelerators have been changed in Xfce Terminal. If you have already tried changing the menu accelerator in Xfce Terminal, then you will see one more additional line as follows.

```
/home/USERNAME/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm
```

If the additional line is not seen immediately, then update the database for `locate` command by running `sudo updatedb.mlocate` in Terminal. Finally, run again `locate accels` and matching results will be updated as above.

Tested working in Xubuntu 14.04 (Xfce 4.10).

**TL;DR** Delete config files, then restart applications. Back to default.